# React rerender causing background image to change

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React component that generates a background image that is random with each visit to the page. However, I do not want it to update with each rerender. This is happening now as a user types text into an input, the background image is updated each time. I have tried to use the useMemo hook without success. What am I doing wrong?

```
export function RegisterLayout({ children, position = 'justify-center' }) {
  return (
        ...
          <img
            src={getBackgroundImage()}
            alt=''
            className='w-100 absolute inset-0 m-auto box-border block h-0 max-h-full min-h-full w-0 min-w-full max-w-full border-none object-cover p-0'
          />
        ...
  )
}

const getBackgroundImage = () => {
  const backgroundImages = Array(backgroundImage1, backgroundImage2, backgroundImage3, backgroundImage4)
  const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * backgroundImages.length)

  return backgroundImages[randomInt]
}

RegisterLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.array,
  position: PropTypes.string
}

export default RegisterLayout
```

Comment: If `backgroundImages` never changes, declare it **outside** the component

Comment: @AdamJenkins I have done that and it still is updating with each text input.

Comment: No you haven’t. Use the original code that was in the question you originally posted, but put `backgroundImages` outside the function. That should be the only change. You changed many things other than that one change since I posted my comment.

Comment: What you did was move backgroundImages out of the component, but then you put it into the getBackgroundImage function and got rid of your useMemo - a bunch of changes

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to load a random background image only on mount I'd probably replace useMemo with useEffect, passing in an empty array as a second argument. This should prevent it from changing with each re-render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getBackgroundImage = () => {
    const backgroundImages = Array(backgroundImage1, backgroundImage2, 
    backgroundImage3, backgroundImage4)
    const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random()*backgroundImages.length)
    return backgroundImages[randomInt]
  }
  return (
    <img src={getBackgroundImage()} />
  )
}, [])
```